# Slope of a 3D curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let a surface $z = x^2-y^2$ be cut by a plane $y = 3x$. Then it will create a curve of intersection. The questions asks what the slope of this curve at $(1,3,-8)$ is.

I substituted $y$ by $3x$ in $z = x^2-y^2$ to get $z = -8x^2$. Then, I computed the partial derivative with respect to $x$, and got $-16$. Nonetheless, the answer is $-8\sqrt{2/5}$.

I assume my method is flawed. Please let me know how to tackle this one.

Answer (score 1):

The slope is defined relatively to an axis which must be on the plane where the curve lays, not relatively to an axis outside the plane.

Your result $-16$ corresponds to the $x$-axis which is outside the plane $y=3x$. That is the reason of the discrepancy.

You have to define an axis in the plane, obviously $\left(y=3x \ ,\ z=0 \right)$, a unit vector on this axis, and a variable, for example $t$. Show that $t=\sqrt{10} x$.

The slope is $-16\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the total differential on $ x,y$ and then with respect to radius.

$$ r^2 = x^2 + y^2 $$
$$ \dfrac{dz }{dr} =\dfrac{ \partial z}{\partial x} \dfrac{dx}{dr}+\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y} \dfrac{dy}{dr} 
 $$